# how do I fix incorrect autocorrect in Safari?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, auto-complete

Whenever I type my email into Safari, (Safari only) whether it's in a text field or filling out a form it misspells it and it's incredibly annoying. The weird thing is that it isn't even my whole email, its just part of it, that it wrongly autocorrects. I can't find anywhere where I've ever typed it in wrong. Any suggestions?

---

When I type: "**MyName@gmail.com**" it autocorrects to "**MyNam@gmail**" before I can even type the "**.com**"

---

I have already tried to go to: **System Pref. > Keyboard > Text**  
 as well as **Right-Click > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar > "Learn"** 
 but neither have worked.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the system dictionary has accidentally learned the wrong spelling at some point. In other apps, you can right-click on the mis-spelled word and there's an "Unlearn Spelling" option. For some reason, this option doesn't appear in Safari, but if you type the mis-spelled version into another app -- e.g. TextEdit -- and right-click on it, does it appear then? (A bit of testing here suggests it might!)

Comment: Alternatively, you can have a look at ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary (it's a plain text file), and see if the mis-spelled version is in there.

Comment: Type it in once correctly - backspace/delete the last letter then you will get the correct one in the list + the old one